# Entity Framework Core 2.1 - Generic Model in FromSql method

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I have been using the below approach to call stored procedure in EF core 2.1

In DBContext

```
public DbQuery<SomeModel> SomeModels { get; set; }
```

Class

```
var result = context.SomeModels.FromSql("SQL_SCRIPT").ToList();
```

I'm trying to create a generic method to execute all stored procedures so that I don't need to physically attach a model with context each time when I call a stored procedure. I'm looking for something like what I have below (Ignore the syntax). Please advice.

```
public Response SoftDelete<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    var result = context.<T>.FromSql("SQL_SCRIPT").ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
    var result = context.Set<T>().FromSql("SQL_SCRIPT").ToList();
```